# Дождаться всех ответов с сервера

Tags: javascript, node.js

Здравствуйте, есть сервер на Node.js, делает несколько запросов на другой сервер и выводит данные на экран пользователю. Сервер перенаправляет запрос в функцию старт, которая и делает запрос.

```
var http = require('http');

function start(response, postData) {

    var arrAnswer = [];     

    if(postData != ''){
        var arrIdStrings = querystring.parse(postData).text.split(','); 
        //в массиве arrIdStrings лежат числа            
        for(var i = 0; i < arrIdStrings.length; i++){           

            var options = {
                hostname: 'example.net',
                path: '/api/'+arrIdStrings[i],
                method: 'GET'
            };  

            var req = http.request(options, function(res) {         
                res.setEncoding('utf8');
                res.on('data', function (answer) {
                    arrAnswer[i] = answer;                          
                });     
            });

            req.on('error', function(e) {
                console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
            });
            req.end();      
        }
        //в someFunction хочется передать весь arrAnswer
        someFunction(arrAnswer[i]);             
    }
}

exports.start = start;
```

Вся проблема в том, что в someFunction приходит пустой массив, как я понимаю из-за того, что запросы еще не выполнились, а функция someFunction уже вызвалась асинхронно. Как дождаться все запросов и передать arrAnswer в someFunction?

Answer (score 1):

Так как код асинхронен стоит использовать callback function https://learn.javascript.ru/task/scripts-callback  и как только запрос будет выполнен вызывать callback функцию и в неё передавать результат и отправлять юзеру.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так: организовать счетчик, которому добавлять +1 при отправке запроса и делать -1 при завершении запроса. При достижении счетчиком 0 вызывать коллбек.

Решение, возможно, не очень элегантное, зато простое и универсальное:

```
var http = require('http');

function start(response, postData) {

    var arrAnswer = [];

    if(postData != ''){
        var arrIdStrings = querystring.parse(postData).text.split(',');
        //в массиве arrIdStrings лежат числа

        var counter = 0,
            clb = function(){
                if(--counter === 0){
                    someFunction(arrAnswer);
                }
            };

        for(var i = 0; i < arrIdStrings.length; i++){

            var options = {
                hostname: 'example.net',
                path: '/api/'+arrIdStrings[i],
                method: 'GET'
            };

            counter++;
            var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
                res.setEncoding('utf8');
                res.on('data', function (answer) {
                    arrAnswer[i] = answer;
                });
                //при получении ответа вызываем коллбек
                clb();
            });

            req.on('error', function(e) {
                console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
            });
            req.end();
        }
    }
}

exports.start = start;
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте промисы пожалуйста. Вот пример:

```
var timer = function (length) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    console.log('Init promise');

    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log('Timeout done');

      resolve(); 
    }, length);
  });
};

timer2(3000).then(() => console.log('All done ...'));
```